# Getting object reference error in my MVP application

Tags: mvp, wcsf

I am receiving random object reference error in different modules of my application.The errors m facing is intermittent. I did debug of my code it looks all correct. Moreover, whenever I run into that error and I try again (immediately after I got error) with same steps with same input conditions that error does not come up. This is something which is happening not only in in development regions but also in production regions. I tried to analyze and I got some leads that there might be problem with temporary ASP. But I don't know how that can cause object reference errors. Sometimes I see Source error information like App_Web_ighjds[some kind of ID I guess]. I don't know where exactly the problem is? As far as my code is concerned It looks all fine. I believe if there was problem with my code then it should be reproducible every time. Does anybody have any idea why such error might be happening? If it is issue with temporary asp.net files then what I should do to avoid such error?? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for ideas: I would suspect your module initializers or any DI container initialization.

Look for code that runs only on application start.
I would recommend to reset your web server completely before starting new debugging session.

I would also recommend setting Visual Studio debugger to "Break when an exception is **thrown**", by going to "Exceptions" settings (Ctrl-Alt-E) and checking the "CLR Exception" "Thrown" checkbox.